# npm run "script" doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, npm

This is really weird, I have the following scripts in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "lint": "./node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint src/js/**/*",
   "lint:fix": "./node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint src/js/**/* --fix"
},
```

When I run `npm run lint` I don't get any errors and running `echo $?` immediately after shows `0`.

However, if I run `tslint src/js/**/*` I do get linting errors.

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a host of well-known issues in `npm` arising from the use of globbing. Many of them exclusively impact Windows, while others are "merely" shell-specific.

Try the following.

```
"scripts": {
   "lint": "./node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
},
```

If this didn't immediately persuade you that computers have been a disaster for the human race, you can learn more about why these issues occur in the fantastic *[The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/)*, which covers a surprising number non-Linux portability issues such as this one.

Comment: Nice, that worked, `--project` was not recognized by using `\"src/**/*.ts\"` worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using npm run lint defaults to the tslint in the node_modules of your local project directory, while using tslint src/js/**/* defaults to the the one in your global, you should check if there is a version mismatch which could cause differences in rules

Comment: ya I updated my example, I changed the script to `./node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint` but still the same result

Comment: And just because I was being paranoid, I did `./node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint -v` and `tslint -v` and both print the same version

Comment: wierd, not sure if this will help but it seems like others are having the same issue? https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2357

Answer (score 0):

With `npm-run-scripts` you can omit the `./node_modules/.bin` as [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path) will first look in there.